# Database query with like condition

Tags: 8, database

Currently I am using the following query to select the data from database

```
$result = db_query("select data from {config} where name like '%IPPOOL_POOL%' ");
while ($row = $result->fetchObject()) {
  $ips=$row->value;
}
```

But this generated an error like

> Undefined property: stdClass::$value

Please help me to implement same in Drupal 8.

Comment: You are only selecting the data field, and then try to access value. Of course that doesn't exist? I'm not sure what you expect? Also, querying the config table seems like a *very* bad idea. Do not query arbitrary tables, always use the API's if available. In this case, the config system.

Comment: I would recommend you rephrase your question to what you actually want to achieve and then you might get a better question.

Answer (score 17):

According to  [Drupal db_like doc page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21database.inc/function/db_like/8.1.x)

> Get a database connection injected into your service from the
> container and call escapeLike() on it.

For example,

```
$injected_database->escapeLike($string);
```

Try something like:

```
$database = \Drupal::database();
$result = $database->select('table_name', 't')
    ->fields('t', ['field_1', 'field_2'])
    ->condition('field_1', "%" . $database->escapeLike($string) . "%", 'LIKE')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll();
```

Read [Database api in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/database-api) for a better understanding of database query in drupal 8.

Comment: db_select is deprecated, Dependency Injection would the best, but for the sake of simplicity you should at least use \Drupal::database()->select() instead in the examples.

Comment: @ssibal you right, thanks , I'm going to update my answer

Comment: While all true, that doesn't actually answer the question. db_query() is deprecated but still works perfectly fine, if your query makes sense. The one in the question does not, see my comment above. No amount of refactoring to avoid deprecated functions will change anything about that. db_like() is also only necessary if you have user input that you want to have escaped.

Comment: @YusefMohamadi, link is 404

Comment: Dead link  Database queries in Drupal 8

Comment: @sea26.2 thanks to noticed me. updated

Comment: @dresh  thanks to noticed me. updated

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in syntax for query() (not for condition()) then here how to use like:

```php
$db = \Drupal::database();
$oldTablesPrefix = $db->escapeLike('old_') . '%';
$oldTables = $db->query('SHOW TABLES LIKE :prefix', [':prefix' => $oldTablesPrefix])
  ->fetchCol();
```